# CodeIgniter 3 Share core model between application packages

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I've been googling for a while now but i cant seem to find a solution for my problem. I have an Codeigniter instance with 2 application (back- and frontend).

So i've set up my application folder like this:

- webroot/application

  - Frontend
  - Backend

Now i have similarities between the 2 applications, like models and such. So i created a "common" package, like this (I found this way to do it somewhere on the internet, can't remember where exactly):

- webroot/application

  - Frontend (Standard codeigniter structure)
  - Backend (Standard codeigniter structure)
  - Common

    - config/
    - helpers/
    - language/
    - libraries/
    - models/

It gets autoloaded properly and i can share models and such between the back and frontend. But now i want to introduce a MY_Model, which you have to place in the `core` directory inside your application folder (as documentation says). Of course i want to share the model over the 3 application packages. (I want models within front- and back-end to extend it, but also models in the common package).

This is where i get stuck. I tried putting a `core` folder in the `common` application package, but then i cant even extend it with a model in the `common` package.

```
Class 'MY_Model' not found in /webroot/application/common/models/News_model.php on line 11
```

I cant seem to extend it in any other package either.

```
Class 'MY_Model' not found in /webroot/application/backend/models/Ad_model.php
```

I dont want to replicate the MY_model class 3 times and edit 3 different files each time i add some new functionality.

Is there any way to solve this? I cant seem to figure it out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could move the core directory outside and symlink it back into each structure.

```
$ ln -s {common/core} {frontend/core}
$ ln -s {common/core} {backend/core}
```

Comment: Symlinking is no option. Its shared hosting and i dont have any shell access to the server.Good thinking though, thanks :)

Comment: If it's just that one file; you could just put a file in each place and include the one outside.

Comment: You mean like, manually do a `require_once`? But still, if i make changes to the file, i dont want to have to keep remebering i need to edit the other one. Also i want to reduce duplication, or not even introduce it.

Comment: That is what I mean. You create that file in each location; you require_once the file outside. Then when you edit the file outside; all the files that require it will be updated. You only update one file after you put the file with the require in each location it is needed. You only have the put the require_once in one time and put that file everywhere you need it.

Comment: I guess that will be my only solution. It feels like i am working against the framework tho. Thanks for the usggestions!

Comment: The other option is to edit the autoloader which could compromise other classes being loaded.